# Puppeteer failing with "Missing X server or $DISPLAY", even though I set up everything correctly

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm launching a simple Puppeteer application that scrapes a website. Most of the time it works, but from time to time (randomly), it fails in the middle of the process with the following error:

```
Error: Unable to launch browser, error message: Failed to launch the browser process!
ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(247)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
```

I am running Puppeteer on an Ubuntu machine, and have an X11 display server ready. The value of the `$DISPLAY` environment variable is also set correctly.

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

returns

```
:1
```

Which corresponds to the ID of the X server.

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer this link: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/8148

For me it worked when I did follwing on my UBUNTU22 LTS

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

You can also try doing either of following:

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0
```

or

```
export DISPLAY=$HOST_IP:10.0
```

or

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

or

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```