# Launch NodeJS script with puppeteer on system startup Missing X server or $DISPLAY

Tags: node.js, linux, debian, puppeteer, xserver

I'm trying to launch a NodeJS script using puppeteer with headless = false, this script is run by PM2 (process manager) at startup.
I'm not having a desktop environment, this is run on a remote server that is wired with HDMI and is supposed to display chrome page that my puppeteer drive.

I'm getting Missing X server or $DISPLAY

Do you know how can I proceed to make it work ? I want the X server to take the whole available screen size. I'm on debian.

My current command is `pm2 start npm --name "Worker" --exp-backoff-restart-delay=100 -- start` that start my package.json start script.

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Puppeteer issue #8148](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/8148), [Puppeteer failing with "Missing X server or $DISPLAY", even though I set up everything correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75001682/puppeteer-failing-with-missing-x-server-or-display-even-though-i-set-up-ever)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by installing a desktop GUI like LXDE, and defining the environment variable `DISPLAY=:0` in my program (which references the LXDE screen)